# How to add UIView on UIAlertController

Tags: ios, uialertview, uialertcontroller

How we can add the `UIView` on `UIAlertController` as we can do on the UIAlertView by using `@"AccessoryView"` but now it is deprecated in iOS 8 .
So I want to use it with `UIAlertController` but how?

Comment: Search google, then use a custom control.

Comment: What is custom control? I didn't get it anywhere

Comment: Something specially created, like everything at www.cocoacontrols.com

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try below thing,

```
var alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.ActionSheet);
alert.view.addSubview([YOUR CUSTOMR VIEW]);
```

Hope its helps..

Answer (score 0):

You can subclass `UIViewController` and make `CustomAlertViewController` and use `presentViewController` to display it.

For reference you can see this [link](https://github.com/mattneub/custom-alert-view-iOS7). It works for iOS 8 only.

Comment: Modified my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a UITableView on UITableViewCell , also CollectionView on the UITableviewCell.
you have to specify datasources inside the cell classes according to the cell index.

register the child cell nib inside the  - (void)awakeFromNib function

[self.collectionView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@“childCollectnCell” bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@“childCollectnCell”]

and Specify the datasources and delegates inside class